# ~たる form of a verb

Tags: sentence-final-particles, grammar

Context: a boy is always been a head shorter than a friend of his, and he always said:

> いつか、必ず抜いたるけんな

which I think I can quite understand ("Someday, I'm sure I'll surpass him"), but not really, since the whole `抜いたるけんな` baffles me.

I did some research, and I found that `けん` [can stand for `から`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/47511/%E3%81%91%E3%82%93-in-%E4%BD%90%E8%B3%80-dialect), but I'm not sure this is the case (see later).

About `たる` I found a couple of questions ([this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/40891/please-help-me-understand-this-%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8B) and [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6985/meaning-of-%E3%82%8B-in-%E5%95%8F%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8B)) which don't quite seem to apply, since in the first the structure is different (`stem-たる`, while above is `short past-る`), and in both is attributive, while above it doesn't seem so (unless it's attributive to `けん`, in which case it doesn't mean `から` and I don't understand it's meaning).

About `な` I think it's just and ending particle, maybe for emphasis.

Comment: To be clear, it's short for 抜いてやる. Your understanding of けん and な is correct.

Comment: What does `抜いてやる` imply in this case? It doesn't seem to fall in any of the meaning you gave in the other question; it's just like `The sentence probably just means "I'll do that" (without "for someone")`, so it just means he will grow taller, without "for someone"?

Comment: It's "to surpass him (and show off my potential/power)". Please see the second link, too.