# Use of たら in この権益の擁護には真剣たらざるを得ない

Tags: grammar

たら is a grammar structure which means if...then.
But what does たら mean in this sentence?

> この権益の擁護には真剣たらざるを得ない

The sentence means

> We must be serious about defending this interest

What is the role of たら in this sentence?
It seems that it does not mean if...then here.

Comment: Related? : https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1017/9831 ... Though I think 真剣 is ナリ活用 not タリ活用...

Comment: https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8A-563266#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88
I have found out similar information in this page.  Though I am not sure about the formation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you see is not the conditional -たら, but -[たる](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/139292/meaning/m0u/) + [ざるを得ない](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/89866/meaning/m0u/).

- X **たる** ("be X; being X")
  This form is a vestige of an old sibling of what is now called *na-adjective*, which still occasionally appears in formal speech. It stands particularly for state that is *acquired* (instead of *inherent*), *temporary* (↔ *permanent*), *apparent* (↔ *internal*), or *due* (↔ *actually is*).

Despite what some dictionaries say, it *does* conjugate in the same manner as verbs なる or おわる (consonant-stem; type I) when needed, though most frequently seen in the dictionary form as an attributive to a noun.

- **ざるを得ない** ("have no choice but")
  A fixed phrase to learn by rote, but consists of ざる (*archaic* "not -ing") + を (accusative) + 得る ("be able") + ない ("not"). Since it starts with a negative, words that come before it must be changed into negative form:

> **行か**ざるを得ない
> **見**ざるを得ない
> **同意せ**ざるを得ない (⚠ *suru verbs have an irregular form!*)

and

> **真剣たら**ざるを得ない *cannot but assume a serious attitude*

Comment: Note that the ～たる ending for certain adjectives arose as a contraction of adverbial particle と + copular ("to be") verb form ある (technically the attributive form of あり, itself the classical dictionary form of modern ある).