# How to get this form and how to translate it 思わざるを得なくなる

Tags: translation

Found in the book for JLPT N2 and can't understand the sentence. I have highlighted the text I cant understand, rest of the text no need to translate, added just for clarifying context.

Google translates this as "Because the person who said it has no choice but to lose."

> 文句を言うことはとても大切です。文句を言う力をつけることも必要です。　ただ、いまは、言う「ちから」そのものが若い人から奪われている。なぜか。文句を言うことで、言った人自身は損をしてしまうと**思わざるを得なくなっているからです**。言ったらもっと状況が悪くなる。職場で[疎]{うと}んじられて、クビを切られるかもしれない。[藪蛇]{やぶへび}だろう、ってことなんです。

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/62690/nuance-of-the-structure-verb-stem-of-negative-form-%e3%81%96%e3%82%8b%e3%82%92%e5%be%97%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84-compared-to-ver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

theres a lot of these 「・・・ざるを得なくなる」type sentences, and like what you got from Google Translate it pretty much does mean "No choice but to". It can ALSO mean "cannot help but..." In the context of that block you pasted, what that sentence is saying "By complaining, the individual cannot help but think by doing so he/she will be at a disadvantage"

so like couple examples is like (looked up these sentences via google search):

悪天候のため、今日の遠足は中止せざるを得ない。-Because of the bad weather, we have no choice but to cancel the trip.

その映画は予告だけで面白いので、期待せざるを得ない。-The movie trailer alone was so good, can't help but be excited

not exact translations, but hopefully you get the idea

Comment: Thanks for your help. So I got this grammar point is like saying "思わないわけにはいかない + have no choice". And ty for examples