# Are foreign adjectives always な adjectives?

Tags: loanwords, adjectives

Sitting in a restaurant yesterday I saw a sign advertising a mango flavoured bagel. It was described as `トロピカルな味`.

That just got me wondering... whenever a `外来語【がいらいご】(word taken from a foreign language / "loan word")` is used as an adjective, is it always a `な` adjective?

Are there any examples of loanword `い` adjectives?

Are there any general guidelines as to how loan words are made to conform to Japanese adjective rules.

*(Please note I'm not familiar with linguistics, so even though I'm asking a fairly technical grammatical question, please dumb it down for me as much as possible. Thanks!)*

Comment: 「エロい」 *​runs​*​

Comment: Ah, but エロい didn't appear until エロチック or エロチシズム already had, so the -i adjective was built on a word that had already been accepted into Japanese, even if its origins were foreign...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're OK with エロい　(as discussed in comments), there are examples like:

- エロい
- グロい
- ナウい

But note that these are directly derived from エロ(チシズム), グロ(テスク), and ナウ　("now"). They were not borrowed into the language as -i adjectives; they were borrowed into the language as nouns and/or na adjectives, and then THOSE borrowings were turned into -i adjectives. Ultimately, this is a form of slang/language play along the lines of the verbs タクる for "take a taxi", マクる for "eat at McDonalds", etc.

So, to get back to the original question, yes. Foreign adjectives always start out as な adjectives. This is a clear rule in Japanese dating from the days of strong Chinese influence. Even when the borrowed word actually ends in an -i sound (e.g. ファジー, セクシー), it is still treated as a な adjective when it first arrives in Japanese. But, once they are in the language, they *can* be broken down and then reborn as -i adjectives, a la グロい.

The interesting issue, I think, is: how "real" are these 二世 -i adjectives? On one end of the scale, I think that エロい and グロい are completely unremarkable now in colloquial Japanese. No-one thinks of them as wordplay. At the other end of the scale, I have heard things like セクシくない, but *only* as a joke. Treating セクシー is if it were セクシい, an -i adjective, even though both speaker and listener know that it is not, is unexpected and therefore amusing. Sort of like how in English we might say "You think that's amazing? I can show you something even amazinger!" even though we know that "amazing" doesn't take the "-er" ending.

(Tangent: Note that セクシい is structurally different from グロい: instead of taking the first two morae and making a new stem, it just reinterprets (intentionally misinterprets) the existing sounds of the word セクシー. This may be one reason why セクシい remains at gag level while グロい is already a regular word. Maybe the *only* way to create unremarkable adjectives/verbs from gairaigo in Japanese is to create a two-mora stem and build on that, and any other method will always remain at the humorous level. I haven't looked into this too deeply. It would be especially interesting to look at perceptions of these words among people born before and after they were created.)

Comment: I learned two new slang verbs today .. タクってマクりに行こう :P

Answer (score 1):

Reading up on sound symbolism, I found this

> Nasal consonants like n and m convey warmth, tactuality, softness, and sound more personal and subjective.
>
> > e.g. むちむち　(plump)

The な　in な-adjectives is a nasal sound. I conject that they are subjective descriptions.

---

Also consider the comparison between adjectives ending in ~しい and those ending in ~い:

> For ~しい type adjectives,
>
> > 悲しい
> >
> > 寂しい
> >
> > 楽しい
>
> These are adjectives that cannot be objectively measured, hence subjective. (And also a large majority of them describe psychological states)
>
> ---
>
> For ~い type adjectives,
>
> > 重い
> >
> > 広い
> >
> > 暑い
>
> These are objectively described; they can be measured.

---

**Conjecture:**

For `トロピカル`　there is no objective scale for "tropical-ness" hence it takes on な. It does not take on ～しい since it is not a psychological　description (as most ～しい adjectives are).

For `エロ` my dictionary shows both `エロな` and `エロい`.

So depending on whether subjectivity/objectivity is conveyed, it corresponds to the use of な or　い.

See also ["i-adjectives used as na-adjectives: is there a difference? (e.g. 大きい versus 大きな)"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1853/i-adjectives-used-as-na-adjectives-is-there-a-difference-e-g-versus)

Comment: How do you measure エロい-ness? :P

Comment: @Lukman: Not sure, but I'd like to try. ;)

Comment: @Dave I realise this is not specific to loanwords but I was more of trying to catch all adjectives and subject them to a generic principle(loanwords included). Of course it's mostly theory on my part, but the sound symbolism part was read from Seiichi Makino's and Mitchio Tsutsui's grammar dictionary.

Comment: 憎い... not very objective.