# ii na to omoimasu

Tags: grammar, particles

I read that `... to ii na to omoimasu` means "I hope that ...". Is the `na` here a final particle that adds the first person's subjective feeling to the proposition as in sawa’s answer to [using なafterい-adjectives](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/5951/1328)?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is. It is the sentence final particle.

Answer (score 2):

「と」 is also the quoting particle. Used as such, it is allowed to follow what would normally be considered a complete and independent sentence.