# What's the difference between 大きいケーキ and 大きなケーキ?

Tags: grammar

I'm studying for Japanese exam of the second year and teacher corrected this sentence-mistake:

> 音楽　を　聞いた　あとで、**大きい**　ケーキ　を　たべました。

was corrected to

> 音楽　を　聞いた　あとで、**大きな**　ケーキ　を　たべました。

What is the difference?

Comment: This question is about the exact same thing, though I don't think it answers why your sentence was corrected: [Adjectives functioning both as イ- and ナ-adjective](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6675/adjectives-functioning-both-as-%E3%82%A4-and-%E3%83%8A-adjective)

Comment: Any reason you cannot ask your teacher?

Comment: Also related: [i-adjectives used as na-adjectives: is there a difference? (e.g. 大きい versus 大きな)](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1853/i-adjectives-used-as-na-adjectives-is-there-a-difference-e-g-%E5%A4%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%84-versus-%E5%A4%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA/9610#9610)

Answer (score 11):

Here is an extensive article about this topic.

[「大きい声」と「大きな声」](http://www.urayasu.meikai.ac.jp/japanese/meikainihongo/7/sasaki.pdf)

Very short summary:

- 大きい and 大きな are interchangeable in most cases.
- On average, 大きな is 8 times more frequently used than 大きい which directly modifies the following noun.
- 大きい sometimes means "elder/older". 大きな doesn't.

  > 一番大きい兄さん (the eldest brother) vs. 一番大きな兄さん (elder brother with the largest body)
- 大きな/小さな sometimes expresses the sense of intimacy with the modified noun, while 大きい/小さい doesn't.

  > 小さな胸 (someone's little heart) vs. 小さい胸 (small breast)
  >   (the difference may be not as big as the English translation suggests)
- Some set phrases only accept 大きな.
- Statistical analysis revealed many famous novelists almost exclusively use 大きな in their works, while a few novelists mainly use 大きい.
- And the author failed to find the meaningful difference in usage between 大きな声 and 大きい声, after investigating 440 real examples.

---

Personally, I see no meaningful semantic difference between 大きいケーキ and 大きなケーキ. However, I do feel 大きなケーキ is more common. Sticking to 大きな when it refers to the physical size of something seems to be a safe strategy, and that may be the sole reason your teacher corrected your sentence.

Answer (score 4):

(Going entirely based off my intuition here, so I could be wrong...)

I think both 「大きいケーキ」 and 「大きなケーキ」 are grammatical in that context, but the latter fits much better.

The difference to me seems to be that 「大きな〜」 is the natural choice for a **judgment**, while 「大きい〜」 is the natural choice for a **description**.

Compare

> 大きい車は、ほとんどの人に役に立たない。
>   "Large cars are not useful for most people."
>   (大きな also works here, IMO.)

vs

> 今、すごく大きな車が正面衝突した！
>   "A big car just crashed!"
>   (大きい doesn't seem to feel right to me in this sentence.)

In your case, you are sort of "telling a story", so suddenly being very objective about the size of the cake doesn't really make sense, it's your subjective impression about it that matters, hence 「大きなケーキ」.

Answer (score 0):

Example one, 大きいケーキ is a generalized observation about cakes. Example two, 大きなケーキ is a direct relationship between size and cake. Thus the English equivalency would be in 1) a big cake, and in 2) the cake I ate was huge.

Answer (score 0):

**Difference of how to use**

> "大きいケーキ" ＞ "ケーキが大きい" OK
>   "大きなケーキ" ＞ "ケーキが大きな" NG