# Compound word ending with an adjective stem (形容詞語幹) and used as a noun or a na-adjective

Tags: adjectives, compounds, morphology

The word 大忙{おおいそが}し is classified as a noun or a na-adjective.

If I analyze it correctly, the word 大忙し consists of the prefix (接頭語) "大" and the i-adjective stem of "忙しい." In addition, there is no such i-adjective as "大忙しい."

Out of curiosity, I'd like to ask if anyone knows other compound words that end with an i-adjective stem and are only used as a noun or a na-adjective (its i-adjective form doesn't exist).

Comment: Related question (mentioned a couple of compound words functioning both as イ- and ナ-adjective, such as 四角い／四角な and 真っ白い／真っ白な): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6675/adjectives-functioning-both-as-イ-and-ナ-adjective and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1853/i-adjectives-used-as-na-adjectives-is-there-a-difference-e-g-大きい-versus-大きな

Answer (score 2):

Many adjective stems work like a standalone noun or an element of a compound, for example:

- 丸い - 丸太 - 赤丸 - 丸
- 悪い - 悪者 - 性悪 - ワル
- 黒い - 黒子 - 中黒 - 黒
- 長い - 長靴 - 気長
- 軽い - 軽業 - 手軽
- 辛い - 辛口 - 激辛
- 厚い - 厚着 - 肉厚
- 安い - 安物 - 株安
- 生臭い - 生臭坊主; 有難い - 有難迷惑; 面白い - 面白サイト
- 短い - 手短; ヤバい - 激ヤバ
- 古い - お古; めでたい - おめでた

If you are looking for words like these, the list would be very long. However, 大忙し is different from these in that 忙し seems to be working like a noun *along with okurigana*. And I think such words are rare.

- 柔らかい - 柔らか頭 - お手柔らか
  <sup>(But 柔らか may be a distinct na-adjective)</sup>
- 嬉しい - 嬉し泣き; 苦しい - 苦し紛れ
  <sup>(But the stems do not come at the end of a compound)</sup>
- 愛しい - 愛し(の); 懐かしい - 懐かし(の); 麗しい - 麗し(の)
  <sup>(But these are not compounds)</sup>

I could think of no word that is perfectly like 大忙し...