# is "Ai suru hito" rightly translated as "beloved persons"?

Tags: translation, verbs, adjectives

I'm confused about the phrase "Ai suru hito" being translated as "beloved ones" in the phrase

"Ooshiku tatta wakamono wa 
Ai suru hito o kabaitsutsu "

As far as I understand, aisuru is translated as "to love". But here it is used as an adjective. Is it rightly translated? and if so, is it common for verbs to used like adjectives by placing them before a noun?

Comment: Maybe not related to the problem, but what's "Ooshiku tatta"?

Comment: @naruto found this lol https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1139629656

Comment: Ah, so it's [雄々しく立った](http://sp.uta-net.com/search/kashi.php?TID=7368). It's hard to decipher without kanji.

Comment: it's from the Macross opening song http://www.animelyrics.com/anime/macross/macross.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

愛する人 technically means either "the person one loves" (=one's beloved person) or "the person who loves someone", depending on the context. In this context it's the former because "protecting the person he loves" makes sense here but "protecting the person who loves someone" does not.

It is very common for verbs to be used like adjectives, and that's called **relative clauses**. Unlike English, Japanese relative clauses modifies something that follows. If you don't know Japanese relative clauses, please [read this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14550/5010).

> 若者が　人を　愛する　　　　　(a youth loves a person)
>   ［若者が　＿＿　愛する］ 人　　　(a person whom a youth loves)

Recently I introduced [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1016/5010) to you. Once you understand Japanese relative clauses, it should be more clear why some people say Japanese i-adjectives are grammatically more like verbs, and, in this case, why a normal verb looked like an adjective to you.