# Is this relative clause correct?

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses

> 彼女からは警戒心が剥き出しの刺々しい雰囲気はない

In this sentence, 刺々しい雰囲気 appears as the noun here and being modified by 警戒心が剥き出し. But how could a complete sentence like 警戒心が剥き出し take the particle の to modify another noun? It would make sense if 警戒心が剥き出しの刺々しい雰囲気 is a complete sentence, but there is はない in the end, which means 雰囲気 must be the main noun being modified here. Wouldn't it be more correct if it's something like

> 彼女からは剥き出しな警戒心の刺々しい雰囲気はない?

Comment: I wonder if the writter's intention was 彼女からは警戒心が剥き出す刺々しい雰囲気はない. (剥き出す: (verb version  of 剥き出し) meaning 'to show'). Then the sentence would translate to "From her there is no sharpe atmosphere that her wariness expose". I don't know if there is any grammatical reason for this tho but this makes sense based on context. I found this sentence on a web novel though, so it's possible that this sentence is ungrammatical since natives can make mistakes too.

Comment: The sentence sounds odd to me but for a reason unrelated to your doubt.

Comment: It seems that 剥【む】き出【だ】し is also used as [an adjective](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%89%A5%E3%81%8D%E5%87%BA%E3%81%97) with the の particle, the basic sense being "exposed". In the structure of this sentence, the adjectival phrase 警戒心【けいかいしん】が剥【む】き出【だ】しの would be modifying the noun 雰囲気【ふんいき】.

Answer (score 3):

> But how could a complete sentence like 警戒心が剥き出し take the particle の to modify another noun?

Remember that Japanese has something called a "double subject" construction such as 彼は背が高い, フランスはワインが有名だ and この本は表紙が緑色だ. By pulling out the は-marked argument and leaving the が-marked argument, you can construct a relativized phrase like so:

- 背が高い人
  tall people
- ワインが有名なフランス
  France, which is famous for wine
- 表紙が緑色の本
  a book with a green cover

Your sentence is basically an example of this. 警戒心が剥き出しの is a perfectly valid adjectival (noun-modifying) expression, and it modifies the following noun phrase 刺々しい雰囲気. (Note that むき出し is a no-adjective on its own, and Japanese adjectives are [similar in syntax to verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1016/5010).)

To explain this in more detail, 彼女は警戒心が剥き出しだ is a valid sentence but (この)雰囲気は警戒心が剥き出しだ is not. I think this 警戒心が剥き出しの is a [**gapless** relative clause](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14550/5010) that modifies (刺々しい)雰囲気. Similar examples include:

- カエルが池に飛び込む音
  the sound of a frog jumping into a pond
- 誰かが魚を焼く煙
  smoke from someone grilling a fish
- 彼が学校に行った帰り
  on his way back from school