# Help me understand サービスでは、NTT Com社内の大規模なプロジェクトへの導入も進む「X Managed Platform」を採用した運用・保守を行う

Tags: translation, newspaper-grammar

> NTTコミュニケーションズ株式会社（以下、NTT Com）は29日、ICT戦略の企画立案、システムの設計・構築、運用・保守にワンストップで対応するマネージドサービス「X Managed（クロスマネージド）」を、4月1日に提供開始すると発表した。
>
> ......
>
> サービスでは、NTT Com社内の大規模なプロジェクト**への導入も進む「X Managed Platform」**を採用した運用・保守を行う。([source](https://cloud.watch.impress.co.jp/docs/news/1398831.html))

How should I understand and translate the second sentence? According to Google, it translates as "The service will be operated and maintained using the "X Managed" platform, which is being introduced into large-scale projects of NTT Com". But I don't find it right.

I'm specially not sure about the bold part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google's translation seems legitimate to me. The basic structure is:

> サービスでは、「X Managed Platform」を採用した運用・保守を行う。
>
> In this service, (they) perform operation and maintenance employing X Managed Platform.

And "NTT Com社内の大規模なプロジェクトへの導入も進む" is a relative clause modifying "X Managed Platform".

> NTT Com社内の大規模なプロジェクトへの導入も進む「X Managed Platform」
>
> X Managed Platform, which is being introduced into large projects at NTT Com

(If you're unsure about this relative clause, please read [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/92740/5010).)

Answer (score 3):

Google Translate did a great job (surprise!).  O and V correspond, and so do O2 and V2.

サービスでは、{[<(NTT Com社内の大規模なプロジェクトへの導入)も進む「X Managed Platform」 O2>を採用した V2] 運用・保守を O} (行う V)。

The verb and object are of the sentence are

> 運用・保守を行う

What type of 運用・保守?

> 「X Managed Platform」を  採用した運用・保守を行う

What is 「X Managed Platform」?

> 大規模なプロジェクトへの導入も進む「X Managed Platform」を  採用した運用・保守を行う

Which 大規模なプロジェクト?

> NTT Com社内の大規模なプロジェクトへの導入も進む「X Managed Platform」を  採用した運用・保守を行う

Where do you 運用・保守を行う?

> サービスでは、NTT Com社内の大規模なプロジェクトへの導入も進む「X Managed Platform」を  採用した運用・保守を行う