# にて / で adverbializer?

Tags: grammar, syntax, copula, adverbial

にて is older form of で, and now has literary or archaic nuance. にて itself was created by adding suffix て to に, which is form of copular verb *n-*.

Traditional interpretation (e.g. [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/47361/)) is that 2 main functions of で are:

- Copula form (連用形/Continuative): "is ... and"
- Locative / instrumental case particle

> 1. 私はペンで**静かに**手紙を書いている
> 2. 私はペンで**静かにて**手紙を書いている
> 3. 私はペンで**静かで**手紙を書いている
> 4. 私はペンで**静かと**手紙を書いている
> 5. 私は森で**丸腰に**歩いている
> 6. 私は森で**丸腰にて**歩いている
> 7. 私は森で**丸腰で**歩いている
> 8. 私は森で**丸腰と**歩いている
> 9. 私はあなたと**一緒に**働いている
> 10. 私はあなたと**一緒にて**働いている
> 11. 私はあなたと**一緒で**働いている
> 12. 私はあなたと**一緒と**働いている
> 13. 彼は**突然に**来た
> 14. 彼は**突然にて**来た
> 15. 彼は**突然で**来た
> 16. 彼は**突然と**来た

My analysis is that:

- All these sentences are grammatically correct, although variants with と may be rare or unnatural.
- **静か, 丸腰, 一緒, 突然 in these sentences are adjectives**, not nouns.
- **にて and で have additional function as adverbializer, similarly to に and と** (although で as adverbializer is probably rarer than に as adverbializer). <sub>(Also adverbializer is actually subfunction of copula.)</sub>

  静かに = 静かで = "quietly"

  丸腰に = 丸腰で = "unarmedly"

  一緒に = 一緒で = "combinedly, together"

  突然に = 突然で = "suddenly"
- で in ペンで is locative / instrumental case particle (格助詞) (here instrumental function), and ペン is noun.
- で in 森で is locative / instrumental case particle (格助詞) (here locative function), and 森 is noun.

**Are there any good counterarguments for this analysis of にて / で?**

(Fixed expressions with adjective+に (e.g. 〜になる, 〜にする) are not really counterargument.)

<sub>(Partially related to discussion in [丸腰を見る and no-adjectives](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/101199/))</sub>

Comment: Only 1. 私はペンで静かに手紙を書いている 7. 私は森で丸腰で歩いている 9. 私はあなたと一緒に働いている 13. 彼は突然に来た, or more commonly 彼は突然来た sound correct to my native ears. 「ペンで静かで手紙を書いている」「静かと手紙を書いている」「丸腰に歩いている」とか言わないです。「あなたと一緒で働いている」は意味が違います

Comment: Different words require different particles. There is even [a specialized dictionary](https://dictionary.sanseido-publ.co.jp/dict/ssd13646) though native speakers hardly need it. Not counter argument, but [で](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A7/#jn-148951) has more than locative/instrumental/copula, so you are just oversimplifying and what you're asking is not clear.

Comment: 「あなたと一緒で働いている」 - I think this can only be parsed as a coordination of （私は）あなたと一緒だ and （私は）働いている. It doesn't say whether they work together or not.

Comment: Non-native speaker, but I must say that I agree with @[chocolate](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/9831/) here -- many of your sample sentences are grammatically incorrect.  I will add that I've never seen にて・で described as an adverbializer; that function lies in particle に, but not にて・で.

Comment: This question is based on the wrong assumptions (that these sentences are all grammatical) and it's not clear what to counter.

Comment: There is a particle にて in classical Japanese with the meaning of 'by means of, with', an example from 徒然草 137:202, すべて月花をばさのみ目にてみるかわ, 'Now then, the moon and the cherry blossoms, are they the only things to be seen with the eyes?' (John Timothy Wixted, A Handbook to Classical Japanese).

Comment: It would be appreciated if some commenter(s) wrote full answers explaining at least how they see difference in meaning, and what grammatical functions of words are, between sentences 1 and 3, 5 and 7, 9 and 11, 13 and 15, and whether they consider some of sentences as unnatural OR grammatically incorrect (those are distinct), and why...

Comment: I think で with verbal adjectives, as hinted at above with the remarks on 一緒で, has to be interpreted as the te-form of the copula, thus, 静かで平和な世の中 does not mean 'a quietly peaceful world' but 'a quiet and peaceful world'. 突然で申し訳ございません means '[this is] sudden and I apologize', not '[I am] suddenly apologetic' and so on

Comment: 1,7,9 are natural. All the others are unnatural. Again, it is a matter of how each word connects to particular particles, not of grammatical correctness. Grammatical correctness and meaningfulness (and idiomaticity) are simply different things.