# <adv> versus <adv>+と versus <adv>+に

Tags: grammar, nuances, particle-に, adverbs, particle-と

I often see adverbs used in one of three ways:

1) Adverb appears in isolation in a sentence:

> **あまり** 好きじゃないんですが。

2) Adverb is followed by に

> **別々に** お願いします。
>
> 1970年代後半、多くの罪もない日本の一般市民が **次々に** 失踪した。

3) Adverb is followed by と

> 鮮明な花火が夜空に **次々と** 揚がった。

Notice that in 2b), and 3), it's even the same adverb and the meaning appears identical.  So suppose for a minute we wrote sentence 3) in each of the three different ways:

> 鮮明な花火が夜空に **次々** 揚がった。
>
> 鮮明な花火が夜空に **次々に** 揚がった。
>
> 鮮明な花火が夜空に **次々と** 揚がった。

Is there any difference between these?

I suspect that the first one is wrong, but the second two are identical and both correct.  But I don't know what rule governs this.  And I think (although I don't have an example handy) that the first ( adv only) and second ( adv + に) patterns can also be used interchangeably in certain situations, which would suggest that maybe all 3 can be used interchangeably in some situations, but not others.

Can anyone explain how this works?

Comment: You forgot about く-adverbs.

Comment: You're right, but I don't think I've ever seen those followed by に or と, so I assumed that the alternatives were not valid for く adverbs.  Am I wrong?

If you have examples of idiomatic Japanese sentences with く adverbs followed by に or と, feel free to post them here and I'll edit the OP

Comment: You have misunderstood. に and と turn the (noun) base into adverbs, just as く does.

Comment: Then is the sentence (one of many examples) 「ソフィーは次々届く手紙に興味を示していく。」 ungrammatical?  

http://tinyurl.com/6e7g7vo

Comment: No, because 「次々」 *also* happens to be an adverb as well as a noun.

Comment: Ok, so back to my original question :)  Is there any difference in meaning between the 3 usages?  (BTW, I'm still not sure what く-adverbs have to do with this discussion.  If you can't say, for example, 優しくに or 優しくと under any circumstances, then it seems that く-adverbs should be irrelevant for the purposes of this discussion).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/804/discussion-between-zach-and-ignacio-vazquez-abrams)

Comment: @Ignacio_Vazquez-Abrams You are right that に and と turn the (noun) base into adverbs, but く does not. What く attaches to is an adjectival root.

Comment: The record shows that you have asked seven questions so far and have never marked an answer as an accepted answer.  Please read [FAQ](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask) to learn what you should do after you receive an answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think what's really going on here can be traced back to the two different ways 形容動詞 (けいようどうし: adjectival nouns or "な-adjectives") were inflected. If we look under the 連用形 (れんようけい: the "adverbial inflection", for lack of a better term) column under the first table on [this Wikibooks page detailing Classical Japanese inflection patterns](http://ja.wikibooks.org/wiki/%E5%8F%A4%E8%AA%9E%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8%E8%A1%A8), we find the following two patterns:

> ナリ活用 (the ナリ inflection), such as with 静か【しずか】: 静かなり or 静かに
>
> タリ活用 (the タリ inflection), such as with 堂々【どうどう】: 堂々たり or 堂々と

(The [Wikipedia page on 形容動詞](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BD%A2%E5%AE%B9%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E) mentions that these inflections were derived from the ～にあり and ～とあり forms, respectively, in Classical Japanese.) For the most part the old styles of inflection have fallen out of use, but there are many examples fossilized in Modern Japanese:

> 聖なる夜 holy night (also used as the Japanese title of "Silent Night")
>
> 暗澹【あんたん】たる時期 a dark period

So without getting into the entire class of words that is used as adverbs without any special と or に appendages, we can see that from early on 形容動詞 were split in that some took なり／に to become adverbs, while some took たり／と.

Generally speaking:

- If a word is more commonly used as a な-adjective (that is, if its 連体形 (れんたいけい), the form by which it connects to a noun, is な), the adverbial form will have に.
- If a word typically does not connect to nouns or is more commonly used as an adverb, the adverbial form will usually have と or nothing at all (excepting common forms such as ～になる or ～にする).

These are general rules (and not very good rules at that), and so exceptions, such as 次々, aren't hard to find.

> 静か｛○に／×と／×∅｝話す speak quietly
>
> きれい｛○に／×と／×∅｝整える arrange neatly
>
> ゆっくり｛△に／○と／○∅｝歩く walk slowly
>
> きっぱり｛△に／○と／○∅｝言う say flatly
>
> はっきり｛△に／○と／○∅｝見える [be able to] see clearly

Unfortunately there are no pretty dividing lines between に and と here. This is probably because に and と have both retained their role of "adverbializer" throughout the evolution of Japanese, and neither form succeeded in displacing the other. Boaz Yaniv mentions this phenomenon in his [answer for why some adjectives use な and some use の](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/920/925#925).

Comment: 「ゆっくりに歩く」「きっぱりに言う」「はっきりに見える」はとても変ですし、正しくないと思うのですが、どうして「ゆっくり、きっぱり、はっきり」のところで、「×に」ではなく「△に」とされているのですか？

Answer (score 3):

From what I gather at [Chiebukuro](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1321351983), all three are the same, though the one who answered (dendenko123, a master in Japanese category of Chiebukuro) said that `と` has a slightly formal feeling.

Of course, there are fukushi(`副詞`)-class adverbs that is so popularly used one way, that usage in the other two is almost unheard of, except in idiomatic usage. For example, `あまりに` and `あまりと` is almost unheard of, except for cases like `あまりにも悲惨なできごと` for `あまりに`. There's also `あまりといえば` but the `と` here is not a particle for the adverb.

But `別々` does not belong here. It is a な-adjective (`形容動詞`). Therefore `別々とお願いします` would sound odd.