# What does 意外と mean?

Tags: usage, words

I heard the expression `[意]{い}[外]{がい}といい` in a video. I know that `意外に` expresses something you didn't expect:

> 意外においしいよ。
>   It's delicous! (and I didn't expect that)

Why did I hear `意外と` instead of `意外に`? Is that a specific dialect? Or, is it standard Japanese?

Comment: Related or duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2714/9831

Answer (score 6, accepted):

“いがいといい” is “[意外]{いがい}と[良]{い}い” (unexpectedly good).

意外と is a less traditional synonym for 意外に (unexpectedly), the latter being the 連用形 (continuative form) of the na-adjective 意外だ.

Comment: Can I change 意外に to 意外と in all cases?　　 
Example:　　
意外と簡単。　　
意外とも、昨日は天気予報があたった。　　
意外と知られていない？

Comment: @danieltomio: 意外にも cannot be replaced with 意外とも, and therefore the second example in your comment is incorrect.  Otherwise I think that 意外に can be replaced with 意外と.  The first and the third examples in your comment are correct.  Note that because using 意外と for 意外に is a new usage, some people consider it incorrect.