# はっきりとは/に what's the difference?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> 私ははっきりとは知らない。
>   私ははっきりに知らない。

はっきりに means clearly but I'm not sure about はっきりとは and what's the difference between both.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1962/9831

Comment: 「はっきりに知らない」 sounds unnatural/incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the word class of はっきり. From jisho.org:

[image]

はっきり is an **adverb** that [optionally takes と](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24943/5010). はっきりに is always ungrammatical because it's not a na-adjective in the first place.

は in はっきりと**は**知らない is a contrast marker. In this case, this は implies that the speaker does not know much about the matter, but he *at least vaguely* knows about it.

はっきり(と)知らない can mean "I absolutely know nothing", but usually まったく知らない or 全然知らない is used for this meaning.

Comment: Wow I wasn't even aware of onomatopoeic adverbs so I was treating it as a na-adjective ‍♂️ thanks.