# 「ずいぶん」と「ずいぶんと」の違い

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

「ずいぶん」と「ずいぶんと」の違いは何ですか。

> 例）「まだ**ずいぶんと**時間があります。」

この例文で「ずいぶん」も使ってもいいですか。それとも、これは正しくないですか。

Comment: 使ってもいいです。意味は変わりませんが、「と」を入れることによって少しだけその後に続く部分が強調されるような気がします・・・

Comment: Possibly related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1903/adv-versus-adv%E3%81%A8-versus-adv%E3%81%AB

Answer (score 6, accepted):

「ずいぶん」と「ずいぶん**と**」の違いは最小限であると言ってよいでしょう。品詞的には双方とも副詞ですし、基本的な意味にも差はありません。

強いて違いを探せば、「と」を付けない方がインフォーマルな響きがするという傾向はあると思います。しかし、その差が大きいかと言えば、それほどではないと思います。

相対的に言って、このふたつの単語においては互換性が高いのが事実です。

従って、例文の

> 「まだずいぶん**と**時間があります。」

は

> 「まだずいぶん時間があります。」

と、「と」を省いて書き換えても、同様に文法的であり、意味にも違いはありません。