# Adverbializers of adjectives in Japanese (に, く, と)

Tags: grammar, particle-と, adjectives, adverbs

I went upon some adverbializers that turn the adjective they follow into an adverb, but don't figure out if there is any rule, such as whether one particular particle (e.g. と, に) is used with one particular type of adjectives (e.g. い adjectives, た adjectives).

Comment: I think this question may have already been asked and answered [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24943/what-is-the-purpose-of-adding-%e3%81%a8).  Have a look at that post, and if it doesn't address your specific needs, please update your question post here to clarify.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of adding と?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24943/what-is-the-purpose-of-adding-%e3%81%a8)

Comment: This item is about onomatopeia adverbs, but here my question is about (た et り) adjectives turned into adverbs by と

Comment: You mean like 整然→整然と並べた? ゆっくり should be an adverb, not an adj. Also, I've never heard of り-adjs

Comment: い adjectives! sorry, I am a beginner... 整然→整然と並べた yes I mean that! So here と adverbializes this adjective?

Comment: Your question is still confused.  There is no "り adjective".  In your sample, the と attaches to ゆっくり, which is a ～り adverb, and the と could be analyzed as making that adverbial-ness more explicit or emphatic -- と is optional after ～り adverbs.  For ～たる adjectives, the ～たる ending itself is a contraction of ～とある, where the と is indeed the adverbial.  Same as ～な adjectives, where ～な came from ～なる, which came from ～にある, where に is the other adverbial particle.

Comment: Thank you! So と is the adverbial particle for た adjectives, に for な adjectives, is と also the adverbial particle for い adjectives?

Comment: Some adverbs take the と particle but others don't. I'm not aware of a rule. But there are lists: https://www.japandict.com/lists/adv-to

Comment: I think this other question might also be useful, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1903/adv-versus-advと-versus-advに

Comment: @starckman, to make an adverb of an ～い adjective, drop the final い and replace it with く.  No と involved.  :)

Answer (score 3):

(Synthesizing answers from the comments)

Although there are exceptions:

〜な adjectives are commonly adverbialized by に.

〜い adjectives are commonly adverbialized by く.

〜たる adjectives are commonly adverbialized by と.

Adverbializers like と can also be used to emphasize the adverbial nature of adverbs.