# これは地図に経緯度が使われるようになってからの習慣であって、古い地図には南が上のものも多い

Tags: grammar

> **これは**地図に経緯度が使われるようになって**から**の習慣**であって**、古い地図には**南が上のものも多い**。
> ([source: line 8-9](https://www.docdroid.net/847v2dg/img-20170413-0001-new.pdf.html))

1. これは
   What does this これ represent? I guess it shall somehow pick up what was said before, but for that, I learnt that そ- is used. So I'd like to know whether it does the same thing as そ- here or something else.
2. から
   I guess this から has a temporal function and confers anteriority here?
   Since I have issues with the sentence in general, I'd like to confirm this, because I really don't know whether my interpretation of the sentence is reliable or not with so many uncertainties around...^^
3. であって
   て-form of である right?
4. 南が上のものも多い
   I really don't know what to make of this.
   First, もの. What is it? I guess its 物, but I'm not 100% sure.
   Second, as I said, I have no idea what to do with this phrase.
   I don't really know what to do with the particle も here, and while I do know that Japanese can work perfectly with nominal phrases only, I simply don't know what this part wants to tell me content-wise.

---

To give an overview how I interpreted these elements in context, here's my try at translating it as far as I could:

> *This* since on maps longitude and latitude being used *habit being there*, on old maps the south has many upper things/things on top.

In my interpretation, I treated the parts in italics as one syntactical unit. Their correlate in the Japanese original would be これは...習慣であって.

Comment: 南が上のものも多い means on old maps the south is often up. ものrefers to the old maps to which this statement applies.... As far as I am concerned, even brand new maps rarely put north up  which confuse the hell outta me every time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. これ can refer to what is previously mentioned, just like *this* in English. In conversations それ is usually used to refer to what the other person said (それは違います = "That's incorrect"), but in written documents これ is primarily used to refer to something just said in the previous sentence.
2. This から means *since* or *after*. Because it's used with の, this から modifies the following noun, which is 習慣. See: [using の with と,で, から, まで](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33605/5010)
3. Yes であって is the te-form of である. Here this te-form is nothing more than *and* used to connect two sentences and forms a compound sentence.
4. 南が上のものも多い: This もの is a pronoun that is used instead of repeating 地図 again. The English equivalent is *one* as in "I don't have a map, do you have *one*?" This も is simply *also*, which can be used in place of the subject marker が. **EDIT:** 南が上の is a mini-sentence "南が上だ", used as a relative clause modifying もの. So a more literal translation is "ones where south is upper". [だ is changed to either な or の](http://www.japaneseprofessor.com/reference/grammar/conjugations-of-the-japanese-copula/) depending on the noun before it. Since 上 is a noun also known as no-adjective, you have to use の. See [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/4914/5010), too. Similar examples are 襟が緑色のドレス (a dress whose collar is green) and 漢字が大量の本 (a book full of kanji).

---

> これは地図に経緯度が使われるようになってからの習慣であって、古い地図には南が上のものも多い。
>   (literally) This is a custom after longitude and latitude started to be used on maps, and, among old maps, ones with south at the top are also abundant.

Comment: Thanks!
I still struggle with 南が上のものも多い a bit.
First, 南が上.
I guess this works like 南が上だ, the copula is simply left out? On jisho, 上 is also classified as a no-adjective, but I haven't learned anything about this category yet, so I can only understand it as a noun so far. 
So  南が上のものも多い is like "_The south is at the top ones_ are also many" to me.
I need confirmation on this because I still feel very unsure about my interpretations of elliptical constructions in japanese, both in determining wether one is there and in determining how to handle it...^^

Comment: @Narktor Please see my edit.