# Regarding the phrase 破れないのが不思議なくらい指に力がこもっていた。

Tags: particle-が

So from the context I expect to mean the same thing as 不思議なくらい指に力がこもっていたが、封筒は破れなかった/封筒が破れるにはならなかった。But in that case, what way 破れないの is the subject, and does it have　(withが) the meaning of なのに ?

Answer (score 1):

The が that appears in this sentence doesn't mean "but"; it's the subject marker.

破れないのが不思議だ = It is strange that it doesn't break.
破れないのが不思議なくらい = So much that it's surprising it doesn't break.
破れないのが不思議なくらい指に力がこもっていた = I was gripping it so hard that I'm surprised it didn't break.

I think you have to treat な as a pre-noun form of the copula (see [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4879/relative-clauses-without-verbs)). 破れないの is not the subject of こもっていた, but of a hidden copula.