# How does "noun + が + noun + の + noun + は" work?

Tags: particle-の, particle-が

> **治療費が未納の方は**お断りしています。

方 is かた, not ほう, right?
I didn't know you could write/say this in this way. I would have said 治療費**の**未納**の**方**は**.

Can you make similar examples?

Comment: Yes you are right that 方 is read as かた. You may find [this related question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4879/relative-clauses-without-verbs) useful.