# Must a relative clause with な adjective be ended with な rather than だ?

Tags: grammar

In my opinion, the usage of だ is already correct in the following sentence. But someone in my other questions said it is incorrect.

For example,

- 映画を見ることが好きだ女性は私の妹です。The woman who likes watching movies is my younger sister.
- 使い方が便利だ電気機は何ですか。 What is the electric appliance that is handy to use?

For the sake of completeness and comparison, I provide relative clauses with a verb, i-adjective and noun as follows. I think they are also correct.

- a verb: 映画を見ている女性が誰ですか。Who is the woman watching a movie?
- i-adjective: 物価が安い町に住みたいです。I want to live in a town whose living cost is cheap.
- noun: ジェットさんが２０歳だ映画を見ています。I am watching a movie in which Mr. Jet was 20 years old.

Must I change every だ to な in the given examples above? Please correct me if it is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you do have to change it.

It is ungrammatical for だ to appear at the end of a relative clause. If you need to have a (present-tense) copula at the end of a relative clause, it must be changed to either な or の. Which of these it changes to will depend on the noun attached to it---some turn into into な (like 好き or きれい), some turn it into の (like 普通 or 緑), and some can turn it into either な or の (like 特別).

> この映画が好き**だ** → 好き**な**映画(を見る)
>   この花は緑**だ** → 緑**の**花(を摘んだ)

The former group is where the term "na-adjective" comes from. Which group a given word falls into isn't really predictable. [(See this question for more detail)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/920)

However, only だ must be changed in relative clauses. Past-tense だった can remain as it is in a relative clause.

> この映画が好き**だった** → 好き**だった**映画(を見る)

Comment: I chose this answer because you EXPLICITLY emphasized the exception in the present tense. To be fair, l'électeur is also good.

Comment: +1, but I want to point out that this answer assumes that *na*-adjectives are a type of noun.  That's fine, but it's not something everyone believes, so I want to point it out explicitly in case anyone is confused.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be misunderstood about this and it is indeed a fairly common misconception.

> 「na-adjective + だ」

In na-adjectives, the 「～～だ」 form is the 終止形{しゅうしけい} (predicative form), meaning it is used to ***end*** a sentence.  Thus, it **cannot** be used to end a relative clause in front of its final noun.

> 「na-adjective + な」

This is the 連体形{れんたいけい} (attributive form), meaning it is always followed by a noun.  Thus, this is the form to use to end a relative clause since a relative clause will always end in a noun.

(Was it not you whom I explained this to only yesterday?  With 「便利な」?)

---

---

Now, let us go over your sentences.

「映画を見ることが好き**だ**女性は私の妹です。」

Incorrect.  It is 「好きな」.

---

「使い方が便利**だ**電気機は何ですか。」

Incorrect.  Again, な ＞ だ

---

「映画を見ている女性**が**誰ですか。」

Incorrect.  Definitely, は ＞ が.  A ***very*** common mistake among J-learners.  Many use 「が」 as if it were the default subject marker, but it is not.

---

「物価が安い町に住みたいです。」

Correct.

---

「ジェットさんが２０歳**だ**映画を見ています。」

Incorrect.  I wanna scream 「『だ』はsentence ender**だ**！」.

You could say 「ジェットさんが２０歳**の時の**映画を見ています。」

or 「ジェットさんが２０歳**だった時の**映画を見ています。」