# Why use の in this phrase?

Tags: grammar, translation

I was reading some youtube comments and one of them were saying:

> 日本語で他の動画を作成してください﻿

I wonder why use の in this phrase? Since it generally means possession or gives to a certain object some characteristic, like:

> それが岡さんの車です or これの県大会はあこじゃない

Comment: What does 「これの県大会はあこじゃない」 mean?

Comment: @l'électeur I was trying to say "Kore no kentai ha ako janai" I don't know if I choose the right kanji for that...

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't really help, since when I try to understand what you're trying to say, I get a bunch of confusing words. (see attached links)  What are you trying to say in English? See: http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%91%E3%82%93%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84  Also see: http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%82%E3%81%93

Comment: 県大会 means prefectural tournament. あこじゃない dosen't make sense.

Comment: By あこ do you mean あそこ? Many beginners seem to think that since there areこれ　それ　あれ there must also be ここ　そこ　あこ but that's not true.

Comment: あこ is an ancient word that meant "my child".

Comment: @Sweeper I'm sorry I actually meant to say 赤 and not あか

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right to recognize that this usage of の is not the possessive use of the particle.

In Japanese, when we study adjectives, we usually are taught that there are two types of adjectives: い-type and な-type.  For the vast majority of adjectives, this is true, but there is yet another type of adjective that you will encounter in your studies: の-type adjectives.

According to jisho.org, [他 is a の-adjective.](http://jisho.org/word/%E4%BB%96)  Given the context of a YouTube comment, `他の動画` means `other video.`  The person who left the comment is saying the following:

> Please make another video in Japanese.

So you might wonder, "What should I know about the  の-adjective?"  Well, there are quite a few resources on the internet.  I have answered a question about the の-adjective before, and you can find the information [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/48587/22352).  The part in that answer that will be useful to you is in the pictures, where you will find a good explanation about how の and な adjective are related, and how they are different.