# If a word is both a na-adjective and a no-adjective, should I use a 'no' or a 'na'

Tags: grammar

Say I have a phrase 'High Quality Music'. The phrase which seems to correspond with 'High Quality' is 良質, which is both a no-adjective and a na-adjective. In this case, when trying to link it with the noun for music, 音楽, should I use no or na? Would it be 良質な音楽 or 良質の音楽?

All help is appreciated :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to choose between a na- and a no-adjective form of a word that takes both?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/46690/how-to-choose-between-a-na-and-a-no-adjective-form-of-a-word-that-takes-both)

Answer (score 7):

In this case, 良質な音楽 and 良質の音楽 are interchangeable and both are equally fine. Maybe the former is relatively colloquial and the latter sounds a little stiffer.

However, just because a dictionary says a word is both a na- and no-adjective does not always mean they are totally interchangeable. There are often times when one is far more common than the other (see [Is there a difference between 最高の and 最高な?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/48585/5010)), and there are even times when using の instead of な changes the meaning. For example 無垢な means "pure and innocent (person)" whereas 無垢の usually means "unfigured (dress)" or "solid (wood, as opposed to veneer)."

Comment: 個人的な見解ですが、良質の音楽という言い方は聞いたことがないです。no-adjectiveはなにかと比較する場合に使う気がします。

Comment: @Wataru'Watson'Subridge え？　BCCWJでも[これ](http://collocation.hyogen.info/word/%E8%89%AF%E8%B3%AA/no)でも山ほど「良質の～」の例は出てきますし、Googleでも「良質の音楽」そのものの例が数え切れないほどヒットしますし、私はそれらの例に僅かな不自然さも感じませんけど…。もちろん、別に具体的な何かと比較しているわけでもないものが殆どです。

Comment: それ見ましたぁ。やっぱり耳にはしっくりこないです。例えば粗悪なとか下品なとかに対比すふ文脈の中では自然に思えるんですけど一口に良質のという形容動詞は他にそれより劣るものがある前提があって初めて使えると思います。

Comment: @Wataru'Watson'Subridge 本当に検索結果をご覧になりましたか？　「ラウンジから流れる良質の音楽とともに食事を楽しめる」「京都から良質の音楽を世界へ」といった‌​例が何の工夫もなしに幾らでも見つかります‌​し、逆にわざわざ何か粗悪な曲と比較対比す‌​る文脈の記事を見つける方が難しいです。そ‌​の意見だと、世の中の「良質の音楽」の例はほぼ全部誤用だと主張しているに等しいと感じま‌​すが…。

Comment: しっくりこないだけで誤用とは思いません。とりあえず意味は120%通じます。自分の受け止め方ですが、「良質の」方が「良質な」よりもより良質に限定したいという話者の意図を感じます。