# "一般の人" or "一般の な人 " ,which the right one?

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

It's confuse me the usage of の and な adverb.

Comment: You didn't mean to include the の in the second one did you?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/48585/7810

Comment: Also, I believe it's "adjective" not "adverb".

Answer (score 1):

一般 is so-called a no-adjective, so you have to say 一般の人. (Jisho.org says 一般 is also a na-adjective, but I don't know when one can say 一般な.) 一般のな人 is always ungrammatical, and you can never say AのなB in general.

Related:

- [So-called の-adjectives - how does の *really* work?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2770/5010)
- [If a word is both a na-adjective and a no-adjective, should I use a 'no' or a 'na'](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55212/5010)