# NO adjectives list or complete explanation

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-に, particle-の

how can i distinguish between no adjectives and noun? particularly, No adjectives are joined with a `ni` particles, Is there any full list or something to remember about them ?

Comment: Can you explain this a little bit more? → No adjectives are joined with a ni particles

Comment: Related, maybe? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/2771/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/920/9831

Comment: @JACK It's better to search for particles as a [tag](https://jisho.org/search/%23words%20%23prt)